# Confusing Effects after Set Options transaction

Tags: effects

I'm not seeing what I'd expect to see from the effects API endpoint.

I created a test account `GBFYP5PVDTKVH2WYR73PUMP463SHU726S5KN6JJ632M7SG7OGLU3CFKN` and funded it.

Then I issued [this transaction](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAEuH9fUc1VPq2I%2F2%2BjH89uR6f16XVN8lPt6Z%2BRvuMumxAAAAZABtt1oAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHuMumxAAAAQIHGSm0bd0tD9Av1DdnWcc3oZuI0XQkOLRjojjtoeOiDQeKjl%2FYsO%2B5DOXrxYEtnjsgrkjJ5Rs2blH56dUAnzgg%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test) to change set the options `AuthorizationRequired` and `AuthorizationImmutable`. The value `setFlags=5` indicates that these values were set.

But when I explore the [effects for this account](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GBFYP5PVDTKVH2WYR73PUMP463SHU726S5KN6JJ632M7SG7OGLU3CFKN/effects), I see.

- `account_created`
- `signer_created`
- `account_flags_updated` with `auth_required_flag=true`
- `signer_updated` with no perceivable change to the signer.

Firstly, why is there no mention of the setting of `auth_immutable`?

Secondly, why does the signer get updated when it doesn't change?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Horizon. I created a new [issue](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/294) in GitHub repository.

Comment: There is also a similar [bug](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/252) with account `inflation_dest` update.

Comment: Given that this is a bug and an issue has been reported on GitHub, please close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a discovered bug and is documented in Github issues at https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/294